# The integral of absolutely integrable function is unaffected by refinement

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

This is part $(5)$ of Exercise $1.4.41$ in Tao's "An Introduction to Measure Theory".

Show that if ${f \in L^1(X,{\mathcal B},\mu)}$(the space of absolutely integrable functions), and ${(X,{\mathcal B}',\mu')}$ is a refinement of ${(X, {\mathcal B}, \mu)}$, then ${f \in L^1(X,{\mathcal B}', \mu')}$, and ${\int_X f\ d\mu' = \int_X f\ d\mu}$. (Hint: it is easy to get one inequality. To get the other inequality, first work in the case when ${f}$ is both bounded and has finite measure support (i.e. is both vertically and horizontally truncated).)

Attempt: We already have the fact that simple integral is insensitive to refinement. It looks like the same property of a general complex-valued $f$ follows from that of the real-valued $f$, which follows from that of the unsigned $f$, which then follows from that of the simple $f$.

Question: Where exactly does the hint come into play?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the same trick as the proof of Theorem 1.4.37 in Tao's book.

For every simple function $f'$ in the refined space, you need to find a simple function $f$ in the initial space which is very close to $f'$ in integral. And $f$ can be exactly the simple functions $f_{\epsilon}$ ($f^{\epsilon}$) in the proof of theorem 1.4.37. Then you can find the difference between two simple functions will not exceed $\epsilon$ in every small subset. Of course, you need the bounded and finite measure supported condition. And later you can prove it's true for generalized situations, just as the author did in the proof of theorem 1.4.37.